# Ctrl key press condition in WPF MouseLeftButtonDown event-handler

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, keyboard

How I can add an additional condition for a certain keyboard key, to a WPF `MouseLeftButtonDown` event-handler?

For example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + key

```
private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{         
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    if(Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl)) {
        MessageBox.Show("Control key is down");
    } else {
        MessageBox.Show("Control key is up");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 43):

If you want to detect modifiers only, you can also use:

```
if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control) {}
if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift) {}
```

etc. More [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.modifierkeys.aspx).

Comment: This solution is simpler

Comment: Don't forget that `ModifierKeys` is a flag enum. So, properly checking for ctrl press is `if ((Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) == ModifierKeys.Control) {}`

Comment: @mt_serg you can make it even simpler by calling `if (Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Control)) { }`

Answer (score 14):

In .NET 4.0 you could use:

```
Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Control)
```

Comment: Be careful though. You don't want `HasFlag()` on a hot path. On .NET Framework, it produces garbage on each run. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11665279/why-enums-hasflag-method-need-boxing).

Comment: This code returns true if Ctrl+Shift (or Ctrl+Alt) is pressed. This may or may not be the intended result. If the intention is to handle the exact Ctrl+<key> combination, then the equals operator is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As Grzegorz Godlewski said [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34198469/3856798), `Keyboard.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKey.Control)` can be used.

Although @l33t points out it is not very performant, in the comment it appears there have been improvements in the performance of `HasFlag` in .NET 4.5/4.6. (see benchmarks results in [What is it that makes Enum.HasFlag so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7368652) and the comments below, and also [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11665571)).

But still nothing as fast as doing a native check (i.e. flagsToCheck & flag != 0 ) judging by the conclusion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71038210).