# Check if an enum contains more than one flag

Tags: c#, enums, enum-flags

I am trying to check if an "enum instance" contains more than one flag.

```cs
[Flags]
public enum Foo 
{
  Bar = 1,
  Far = 2
}
```

```cs
var multiState = Foo.Bar | Foo.Far;

MoreThanOneFlag(multiState); // True

var singleState = Foo.Bar;

MoreThanOneFlag(singleState); // False
```

Additionally I really don't wanna use something like the following:

```cs
var state = Foo.Bar | Foo.Far;

Console.WriteLine(state.ToString().Count(x => x == ',') > 0); // True
```

Note, I do not care which Flags the "instance" contains, I just want to know if there are more than one.

Comment: There are so may duplicates, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339976/how-to-check-if-any-flags-of-a-flag-combination-are-set) You can use and `&` operator or `HasFlag` method

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I already looked at those, I just want to know **if**, there is more than one flag set. These answers check if a specific flag is set.

Comment: Perform a bit operation... `bool value = (multiState & (multiState -1)) != 0;`

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ That was actually exactly what I was searching for. Sadly I just noticed I could have searched for set bits, bummer.

Comment: Do you have only two flags? (and therefore only one combination of multiple flags) or are you looking for a general solution to this problem

Comment: @Steve This is just a simple example, it should work for any amount of flags.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting the number of flags set on an enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677204/counting-the-number-of-flags-set-on-an-enumeration)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I didn't really want to count it, the solutions differ, even when just slightly.

Comment: Why do you want to know if your value is a combination? Usually you just want to get the included bits.

Comment: Maybe they want to check for illegal combinations

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ This should be answer rather than a comment.

Comment: @Liam yes, but actually no. Under this post there are a lot more answers, which are IMHO better suited, for me at least. Additionally some of them are even more faster.

Comment: Well those answers should of been added to the older question(s). This should of been closed as a dupe 9 months ago as the question has already been asked multiple times. In fact this is the obvious dupe target for both, [How do I check if more than one enum flag is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949567/how-do-i-check-if-more-than-one-enum-flag-is-set)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to check if an "enum instance" contains more than one flag.
>   I do not care which Flags the "instance" contains, I just want to know if there are more than one
>
> Additionally I really don't wanna use something like the following:

```
 var state = Foo.Bar | Foo.Far;
 Console.WriteLine(state.ToString().Count(x => x == ',') > 0); // True
```

There are more than a few different ways to accomplish what you want, I propose to do a bit (bitwise) check:

```
 public static bool MoreThanOneFlag<TValue>(TValue flag) where TValue : Enum => (Convert.ToInt32(flag) & (Convert.ToInt32(flag) - 1)) != 0;
```

In the above code block, we check if `flag` *is not a power of two* by checking using `flag & (flag-1)) != 0` (the & operator) which computes the bitwise logical AND of its operands. If there's only one flag set, we assume then that the value would be a power of two, otherwise it's a non power of two.

Or, if you don't want a helper function just perform that check anywhere:

```
 bool value = (multiState & (multiState -1)) != 0;
```

For more information about bitwise, [please check out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#logical-and-operator-) more here.

References :

[Bitwise and shift operators (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators)

Comment: I love it! You don't need to use Convert.ToInt32, though. Just casting to int works fine. If you're being REALLY complete, you have to check the integral type and use it for the values. Out of scope for this, though. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the binary logarithm function on the `enum` value and then check if the result is an integer.

The following example defines am Extension Method helper, which returns `true` when multiple flags are set:

**HelperExtenxsions.cs**

```
public static class HelperExtenxsions
{
  public static bool HasMultipleFlags(this IConvertible enumValue) 
  {
    return Math.Log(enumValue.ToInt32(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat), 2) % 1 != 0;
  }
}
```

**Foo.cs**

```
[Flags]
public enum Foo 
{
  Bar = 1,
  Far = 2
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
public static void Main()
{ 
  var enumValue = Foo.Bar | Foo.Far; 
  Console.WriteLine(enumValue.HasMultipleFlags()); // Prints 'True'

  enumValue = Foo.Bar;
  Console.WriteLine(enumValue.HasMultipleFlags()); // Prints 'False'
}
```

Comment: Enum is a valid constraint in modern c#. You can do TEnum : Enum

Comment: Yes, correct. But I think you cannot simply convert `Enum` to an integer value using a cast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enum.GetValues` in *conjunction* with `Enum.HasFlag(Enum)` to iterate over each *constant* & determine  if the bit field(s) are set in the current Instance and return its count.

```
[Flags]
public enum Foo
{
  One = 1,
  Two = 2,
  Four = 4,
  Eight = 8
}

var state1 = Foo.One;
var state2 = Foo.Two;//
var state3 = Foo.One | Foo.Two; 
var state4 = Foo.Two | Foo.Four;

Console.WriteLine(MoreThanOneFlag(state1));//false
Console.WriteLine(MoreThanOneFlag(state2));//false
Console.WriteLine(MoreThanOneFlag(state3));//true
Console.WriteLine(MoreThanOneFlag(state4));// true
```

```
private static bool MoreThanOneFlag<TEnum>(TEnum state) where TEnum : Enum
{
  var names = Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum));
  var Flagcounter = names.OfType<TEnum>().Where(x=>state.HasFlag((TEnum)x)).Count();
  return Flagcounter > 1 ? true : false;
}
```

*Note:* While `Enum.HasFlags` may not the apt solution if you're app demands performance but it is much [reliable, clean, and makes the code very obvious and expressive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7368674/4686729)

*Reference:*

[C# Enum.HasFlag vs. Bitwise AND Operator Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39493944/c-sharp-enum-hasflag-vs-bitwise-and-operator-check)